# How do I extract data from a registry subkey and assign it to an appropriate class property

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, loops, properties

EDIT: I know how to extract data from the registry. I have a different issue. Please read the question in its entireity.

Imagine that I have a class named "Car" with the following properties:

Manufacturer (required)

Model (required)

Registration (required)

Weight (Optional)

Tyres (Optional)

...........

and 15 more optional properties

Every detail of every particular car is stored in the Windows Registry in the following manner:

\\Cars\CarID

Each CarID subkey contains these values in the following format. For Ex

Manufacturer-----REG_SZ-----Ferrari S.p.A

Model--------------REG_SZ-----SP12 EC

Registration-----REG_SZ-----TL6735436

and other optional fields which may or may not be present.

I want to create a loop which iterates through all the values of CarID subkey and assigns them to the appropriate property of a car class instance

Something like this:

```
Dim cTemp as New Car

For Each strTemp as String in keyCarID.GetValueNames
    ctemp.<Appropriate Property> = keyCarID.GetValue(strTemp)
Next
```

The class Car has the same property names as the value names in the registry.

This method will be more efficient than checking whether each property exists or not in the registry.

I am ok with both VB.net or C#

Comment: DId you do *any* research outside of StackOverflow on how to read from the registry with .NET? There are a lot of built-in classes to handle this...

Comment: @Ron. I know how to read from the registry. That's not my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify this example:

```
class D
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int c { get; set; }
}

[....]

D d = new D();
PropertyInfo[] typeProperties = d.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach(string propertyName in new string[] { "a", "b", "c"}) {
    int myValue = 1; // for example
    typeProperties.Single(p => p.Name == propertyName).SetValue(d, myValue);
}
```

so it will look something like:

```
Car car = new Car();
RegistryKey keyCarID = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Default);
PropertyInfo[] typeProperties = car.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (string propertyName in keyCarID.GetValueNames()) {
    typeProperties.Single(p => p.Name == propertyName).SetValue(car, keyCarID.GetValue(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: Had to modify a bit. But this worked. I will post my modified code as a reply later once I test it thoroughly. Marked as Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following VB.net Code

```
        For Each key As String In rk.GetSubKeyNames
            keyValue = keyValue.OpenSubKey(key)

        For Each strValue As String In keyValue.GetValueNames
            giProperty = giInfo.GetType.GetProperty(strValue)

            Select Case giProperty.PropertyType.Name.ToLower
                Case "string"
                    giProperty.SetValue(giInfo, keyValue.GetValue(strValue))
                Case "guid"
                    tempGuid = keyValue.GetValue(strValue)
                    tempGuid = tempGuid.Substring(1, tempGuid.Length - 2)
                    giProperty.SetValue(giInfo, New Guid(tempGuid))

            End Select
        Next
    Next
```

Not all properties of my class returned "String", so I had to modify it a bit. Your answer was the one that help me a lot Roman, so thank you once again.